# VS2017 Linux C++ threads issue

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, pthreads

I have been testing the VS2017 Linux C++ with remote debugger on Linux Ubuntu.
I have created a few example projects for C++ and everything has been working great until I got to threading examples.

I cannot seem to get the threads to compile as I keep getting "undefined reference to `pthread_create'" error. I know the solution to this is to add -lpthread or -pthread to the VS project properties command line but this does not seem to work in this case.

If anyone has got this working could you please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Make sure the `-pthread` is late in the link command line. Certainly after all of your object and library files. Order is important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

linker->input->library dependencies  pthread